# UIButton doesn't receive touch when at bottom of UiScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a nib file that I load in a UIScrollView. In the nib file there are two buttons near the bottom.

The first button works just fine when tapped. However the button directly below it does not work. The nib file does not use auto layout and I am using auto sizing structs / springs to keep views where they should be.

I noticed that on a iPhone 5 the buttons work just fine. However on a iPhone 4 they do not?

Comment: make sure that you have to set @property and action Method and also set it to file's owner

Comment: Have you directly added button on scroll view or used UIView and then added the UIView on scroll view.

Comment: Using a UIVView (the nib file) and adding that whole view to the scrollView. The UiButton is part of the UUiView which is in the nib file.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in iPhone 5 and not in iPhone 4 means, I guess the y Axis of the button would above 480. Because iPhone height is 568, So my guess is second button Y axis would be between 480 & 568. NSLog the button's Y axis and check it.

Comment: Yes it is above 480. But that is why I have the scrollview - to get to it. How would I solve this problem?

Comment: The second UIButton is also above 480.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by playing with the `AutoSizing` springs and structs. Mainly I set them incorrectly. So its something to look at if anyone else has this issue.